# Using join without specifying all properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq syntax where three tables are joined together to return a object with the needed properties. In the example all the properties need to be specified and linked to the corresponding values in order to return the object with the joined data, Prop1 = ta.prop1, Prop2 = ta.prop2 etc. EntityA contains NoMap properties PropB and PropC, hence the end outome is EntityA with the joined values. Is there a way to join data without needing to set each property in the join statement?

```
 var objectWithJoinedProps = datacontext.EntityA
                .Join(dc.EntityB, ta => ta.PropA, tb => tb.PropB, (ta, tb)
                    => new EntityA()
                {
                    Id = ta.Id,
                    Prop1 = ta.prop1,
                    Prop2 = ta.prop2,
                    Prop3 = ta.prop3,
                    ...
                    Propx = ta.propx,               
                    ProbB = tb.PropB
                }).Join(dc.EntityB, tb => tb.PropB, tc => tc.PropC, (tb, tc)
                    => new EntityA()
                {
                    Id = tb.Id,
                    Prop1 = tb.prop1,
                    Prop2 = tb.prop2,
                    Prop3 = tb.prop3,
                    ...
                    Propx = tb.propx,               
                    ProbC = tc.PropC
                })).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Seems a perfect job for AutoMapper: you still have to define the result class, but no need to write all `a=b` statements.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold thanks for the suggestion, how would you call automapper in the query? replacing the new statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is wise to automatically include all properties. If your source tables change, do you want that the users of your query suddenly get other data than specified? Wouldn't it be inefficient to give them properties that apparently they don't use?

Will you have to rewrite your unit tests? Does that weigh up against the extra typing of your Select statements?

If you think so, consider to user [Nuget AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html). By default it will try to copy all properties. It is also possible to ignore some properties (like foreign keys), or to change the values of some properties.

Comment: About reflection, that was years ago :) See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html and http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is:

```
var objectWithJoinedProps = datacontext.EntityA
                .Join(dc.EntityB, ta => ta.PropA, tb => tb.PropB, (ta, tb)
                    => new { TA = ta, TB = tb})
                .Join(dc.EntityB, x => x.TB.PropB, tc => tc.PropC, (x, tc)
                    => new { TA = x.TA, TB = x.TB, TC = tc})
                .Select(x =>
                    new EntityB()
                {
                    Id = x.TA.Id,
                    Prop1 = x.TA.prop1,
                    Prop2 = x.TA.prop2,
                    Prop3 = x.TA.prop3,
                    ...
                    Propx = x.TA.propx,               
                    ProbB = x.TB.PropB                    
                    ProbC = x.TC.PropC
                })).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi @Gildor, I forgot to mention that EntityA contains NoMap properties PropB and PropC, hence the end outome is EntityA with the joined values. So I was hoping  it would be possible to query the entity without listing the properties since they are anyway part of the obj in the first join, hence only listing the joined properties which are missing from EntityA